# React State Object updating without setState

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
class FilterMenu extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        min: 0,
        max: this.getFormatedPrice(this.props.category_maxPrice,false),
        minValue: '',
        maxValue: '',
        searchTerm: '', 
        data: this.props,
        checkedBoxes: [],
        initialFilters: this.props.filters,
        filters: this.props.filters,   

    }
    this.onInputChange      = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
}

onInputChange(event){

    let substr = event.target.value;
    event.preventDefault();

    {(() => {
        var targetFilter = event.target.id;
        var initialFilterItems = this.initialFilters[targetFilter].items;
        var newFilters = _.extend({}, this.state.filters);
        newFilters[targetFilter].items = initialFilterItems.filter(function(item){
            return item.title.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        })
        this.setState({ filters: newFilters });
    })()}
}
```

}

I just want to update "filters" state, which holds some data from "initialFilters".
But when I use this.setState({ filters: newFilters }), it's updating "initialFilters" also

Appreciate your support.

Comment: Does `_.extend` create a deep copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Underscore.js documentation, _.extend makes a shallow copy of the object. That means all nested objects inside your object are copied by reference.

This leads to the **state's** filter's items object to change before the setState method is used.

Furthermore you are passing this.props.filters to initialFilters and filters by reference (no copying occurs). That means changing one of them **will** change the other as well.

To avoid this you need to create a deep copy of the filter object.
The easiest way to do it is by using JSON.stringify.

Refer to this [post](https://medium.com/@tkssharma/objects-in-javascript-object-assign-deep-copy-64106c9aefab) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Efstathios, I use initialFilters: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.filters)), and it works...

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.assign` instead of `_.extend` may help. [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

I noticed that initialFilters appeared twice, if you don't use `initialFilters` when rendering JSX, just put values in `this.initialFilters` can avoid triggering meaningless rendering.